# I'm making a java program to retrieve tweets with a specified hashtag and store them in a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, twitter4j

I started by creating a database that contains a "tweets" table with two fields (ID and TEXT) then I made the connection to the database using JDBC... I'm going to know how to insert tweets in the table... I made a single class that combines authentication to the Twitter API and the database... i'need the help please

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate persistence Away from the retriver’s logic, aka don’t mix up the things.

1. Make a model class Tweet.
2. Define a ITweetRetriver interface and implement it.
3. Define ITweetRetriverListener interface that would be used by ITweetRetriver.
4. Define TweetPersistence interface and implement it as MySQLTweetPersistence.
5. Now in your main create a reteiver, a listener and on listener’s OnNewTweet pass it to persistence.
   Cheers.

Tip. Make Stored procedures on MySQL db and call them from your persistence implementation.